# Changing String to Date in R produces NA

Tags: r, string, date, datetime

I'm trying to change a string to a date object in R. However, it only outputs an NA result.

The code I'm running is:

```
date <- "2005-01"
as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m")
```

which retunrs

```
[1] NA
```

I've been reading other threads that suggest using the system locale to correct this. However, I haven't had any success with this so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste0(date,"-01"))

Comment: This outputs "2005-01-01" however, due to the package I'm using, I need to keep the date in year-month format

Comment: Maybe use `format`: `format(as.Date(paste0(date,"-01")), "%Y-%m")`

Comment: The year-month format is a character representation of a date. You can choose to convert back to that character format if you'd like. But if you want to work with a numeric date field, you need a full date.

Comment: @GKi `format()` returns a character object, not date. The output from your code is equivalent to the original input `date`.

Comment: @cory I posted in the comments to the answer below the documentation I'm following. In the preparing the data section they say monthly data needs to be in the form: dddd-dd for monthly dates, e.g. 2016-03 for March 2016. I don't know if you have any ideas whether this might be a string, datetime object or integer? I attached the link to the documentation below. Cheers

Comment: @DarrenTsai Yes, as `Date` needs a *day* and he wants to convert to `Date` but can use it only when there is no day it has to be something like `character`. If there is a need to convert from character to Date and than back to the same character is for sure questionable but if you want to make some calculations with the date it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

a `Date` in R needs to be a *full date*, and yours is missing a day of the month (`%d` as `strptime` understands it).

You can get around this by supplying an arbitrary day -- the easiest one is the 1st, as @GKi points out in the comments:

```
as.Date(paste0(date, '-01'))
# [1] 2005-01-01
```

You can convert this back to a string using `format` (see `?format.Date`) -- Year-Month format is `format(date_variable, '%Y-%m')`. Note that the output of `format` is *not* a `Date` object anymore -- it's a string again (i.e., you're back where you started).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If this is so, might you be able to advise on how to format the date so it is accepted by the MSCMT package? If you look at the 'Preparing the Data' subheading you will see their instruction. The documentation is here: https://rdrr.io/cran/MSCMT/f/vignettes/WorkingWithMSCMT.Rmd

Comment: @AngusWatson I have edited this in, but I don't think this is what you're after anyway.